# Debug symbols for EPiServer 7

Tags: episerver, episerver-7

I am looking for a way to debug code in EPiServer 7. According to [this blog post](http://world.episerver.com/blogs/Enes-Bajramovic/Dates/2010/4/Symbols-for-EPiServer-CMS-6-available/), debug symbols are available for EPiServer 6. I tried the same approach for EPiServer 7, but symbols do not load.

Are debug symbols for EPiServer 7 available somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently EPiServer has stopped providing debug symbols. Technically one could [generate debug symbols](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/help/Generating_PDB_Files.html) using a decompiler such as the free [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) which also comes with ReSharper. This is not advice to do that.

Decompiling the code is probably against the EPiServer EULA and thus illegal. It was, however, explicitly recommended to me by an EPiServer trainer in the EPiServer CMS MVC Development course.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if any documentation exists on this?

Comment: I don't know of any EPiServer-specific decompilation documentation. DotPeek obviously has its own documentation. E.g. https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/help/Generating_PDB_Files.html might interest you.